# terminal displays localhost before username osx

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm working on getting GIT installed so starting to use my terminal more. 
Noticed something odd though. The word `localhost:~` before my username

so `localhost:~ username$`

Is this something I need to be worried about? Just I'm following some tutorials and all of them so far just have the user name like

```
username$
```

Done a bit of searching and found nothing on this so far and just wanted to check before I move on any further.
Thanks

using osx 10.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to worry about. `localhost` is the name of your machine, followed by :, followed by the directory you're in, in this case `~`, which is your home directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also have file sharing enabled, which I forgot to mention.